# Fatal error while trying to delete data from firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, error-handling

Im trying to delete data from Realtime database using a Recylerview, where I see the list of users and i can delete from there, the problem is that after deleting about two users in a row the application stops and i get the following error:

```
021-05-23 22:59:53.813 28596-28596/app.com.health E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: app.com.health, PID: 28596
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 51, Size: 51
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.firebase.ui.common.BaseObservableSnapshotArray.getSnapshot(BaseObservableSnapshotArray.java:70)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getRef(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:112)
        at net.smallacademy.authenticatorapp.myadapter$2$1.onClick(myadapter.java:124)
        at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:191)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
```

with the line(124)being:
`.child(getRef(position).getKey()).removeValue()`;
the code for this adapter where i've implemented these methodes of deleting and updating is:

```
public class myadapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Calories,myadapter.myviewholder>
{
    public myadapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Calories> options)
    {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final myviewholder holder, final int position, @NonNull final Calories calories)
    {
        holder.food.setText(calories.getName());
        holder.calories.setText(calories.getCalories());
        holder.proteins.setText(calories.getProteins());
        Glide.with(holder.imge.getContext()).load(calories.getImage()).into(holder.imge);


        holder.edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final DialogPlus dialogPlus=DialogPlus.newDialog(holder.imge.getContext())
                        .setContentHolder(new ViewHolder(R.layout.dialogcontent))
                        .setExpanded(true,1100)
                        .create();

                View myview=dialogPlus.getHolderView();

                final EditText name=myview.findViewById(R.id.uname);
                final EditText calories2=myview.findViewById(R.id.Calories_u);
                final EditText proteins=myview.findViewById(R.id.proteins_u);
                Button submit=myview.findViewById(R.id.usubmit);


                name.setText(calories.getName());
                calories2.setText(calories.getCalories());
                proteins.setText(calories.getProteins());

                dialogPlus.show();

                submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Map<String,Object> map=new HashMap<>();
                        map.put("name",name.getText().toString());
                        map.put("proteins",proteins.getText().toString());
                        map.put("calories",calories2.getText().toString());


                        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Food")
                                .child(getRef(position).getKey()).updateChildren(map)
                                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                        dialogPlus.dismiss();
                                    }
                                })
                                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                        dialogPlus.dismiss();
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                });


            }
        });


        holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(holder.imge.getContext());
                builder.setTitle("Delete Panel");
                builder.setMessage("Delete...?");

                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Food")
                                .child(getRef(position).getKey()).removeValue();
                    }
                });

                builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                    }
                });

                builder.show();
            }
        });

    } // End of OnBindViewMethod



    @NonNull
    @Override
    public myviewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.singlerow,parent,false);
        return new myviewholder(view);
    }


    class myviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {

        ImageView edit,delete;
        TextView food,calories,proteins;
        ImageView imge;

        public myviewholder(@NonNull View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);


            food= itemView.findViewById(R.id.nametext);
            calories=itemView.findViewById(R.id.coursetext);
            proteins=itemView.findViewById(R.id.emailtext);
            imge=itemView.findViewById(R.id.img1);

            edit=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.editicon);
            delete=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.deleteicon);
        }
    }
}
```

the error happens cause of something inside "holder.delete.setOnClickListener"
the error is confusing to me and I don't really know what it means therefore I can't fix it, I'd pretty much like some help and thank you.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo it works well but when i delete from recyclerview like 3 times in a row i get the error mentioned above, the application stops